# How to get rid of ampersand using WP Nonce URL and WP Redirect or PHP header

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

My code was working fine:

```
$registrado = "no";

$redirect_url = site_url( "/pedido-nao-recebido/?mpms2pagarme=retorno&codigo=nao200&mensagem=oui&registrado=$registrado");      

wp_redirect($redirect_url);

exit;
```

With this, I was being redirected to

```
http://s16138.p360.sites.pressdns.com/pedido-nao-recebido/?mpms2pagarme=retorno&codigo=nao200&mensagem=oui&registrado=no.
```

Exactly what I need.

Then I decided to take a security measure, with `wp_nonce_url`.

```
$registrado = "no";

$redirect_url = site_url( "/pedido-nao-recebido/?mpms2pagarme=retorno&codigo=nao200&mensagem=oui&registrado=$registrado");      

//WP Nonce (security measure)
$nonce_redirect_url = wp_nonce_url( $redirect_url, 'pedido-nao-recebido', 'mpms2nonce' );

wp_redirect($nonce_redirect_url);

exit;
```

Now I get this URL:

```
http://s16138.p360.sites.pressdns.com/pedido-nao-recebido/?mpms2pagarme=retorno&amp;codigo=nao200&amp;mensagem=oui&amp;registrado=no&amp;mpms2nonce=aeb5ba40d2.
```

Because of these `amp;`, my code is broke and browser gives me a `The s16138.p360.sites.pressdns.com page isn’t working`. There is a script on the redirected page that is not running. It goes like this:

```
//If it is not a subscription request, abort...  
if ( !isset( $_GET['mpms2pagarme'] ) || 'retorno' != $_GET['mpms2pagarme'] || !isset( $_GET['codigo'] ) || !isset( $_GET['mensagem'] )  ) {  
    return;  
}

//Checking WP Nonce
check_admin_referer( 'pedido-nao-recebido', 'mpms2nonce' );

(...)
```

I tried using php `header` function instead of `wp_redirect`, but the same happened (ampersand). I tried also `esc_url`, `esc_url_raw`, `urlencode`...with no success.

Strange thing...`wp_redirect` (or `header`) only works for me without `wp_nonce_url`. Should I get rid of the latter? Any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could pass just the base url to the nonce function, and then append your remaining parameters afterwards.

Comment: It says in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url): `Retrieve URL with nonce added to URL query. The returned result is escaped for display.`

Comment: Hey, James, actually your solution worked for me. Simple and perfect. Great! How can I reward you something here ? (still newbie at stackoverflow...)

Comment: Well, not yet. wp nonce is failing now. Is this because nonce comes first on the URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `html_entity_decode()` to convert `&amp;` back to `&`

Answer (score 0):

The string is being url encoded somewhere along the way

you can decode it with **[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)**

```
wp_redirect(urldecode($nonce_redirect_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this still helps someone:

```
 // This will return the url with & 
 // pedido-nao-recebido/?mpms2pagarme=retorno&codigo=nao200&mensagem=oui&registrado=no&pedido-nao-recebido=noncevaluehere
    
    echo add_query_arg( 'pedido-nao-recebido', wp_create_nonce( 'mpms2nonce' ), $redirect_url );
```

Taken from the comment below:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_url/#comment-1927